# Returning a generated vector in C++

Tags: c++

Three C++ functions that create a vector and return:

```cpp
vector<int> generate_vector_v(int n) {
    vector<int> foo;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        foo.push_back(i);
    }
    return foo;
}


vector<int>* generate_vector_p(int n) {
    static vector<int> foo;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        foo.push_back(i);
    }
    return &foo;
}

vector<int>* generate_vector_m(int n) {
    auto foo = (vector<int>*) malloc(sizeof(vector<int>) * n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        (*foo).push_back(i);
    }
    return foo;
}
```

(I'm not sure if everything is fine with `generate_vector_m()`.)

Are there differences in terms of memory efficiency and run-time speed?

In general, if I want to write a function that creates an object and returns it, what is the preferred way? Should I write something like `void fill_vector(vector<int>& foo, int n)` instead of all above?

I want to make sure that the vector is just created once in the memory without making any copies.

Comment: _"In general, if I want to write a function that creates an object and returns it, what is the preferred way? Should I write something like void `fill_vector(vector<int>& foo, int n)`?"_ `fill_vector(vector<int>& foo, int n)` doesn't create and return a vector. It fills an existing vector.

Comment: With `generate_vector_p(int n)` you are appending a new element to the same vector every time the function is called. Do you want that behavior?

Comment: You never construct `foo` in `generate_vector_m`, so bad things are going to happen.  If you have to allocate memory (and there's no point here), use `new` (or better yet, `std::make_unique`).

Comment: @jabba Yes, it does. I want to make sure that the vector is just created once in the memory, but at the same time, I wanted the calling part simple enough. 

`auto v = generate_vector_v(3);` 

vs. 

`vector<int> foo; fill_vector(foo, 3);`

Comment: "In general, if I want to write a function that creates an object and returns it, what is the preferred way?" Just....write a function that creates and object and returns it.

Comment: Yes there is difference - the first function works, other two do not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`generate_vector_m` The behaviour of the program is undefined, and it returns a bare owning pointer which would probably lead to a memory leak, and it is slow due to unnecessary use of dynamic memory. Don't use it.

`generate_vector_p` appends more and more elements into a single static vector on every call. That's not often useful; global state is problematic. There's also some marginal overhead from synchronisation.

`generate_vector_v` is fine. I would use `std::iota`, but a loop is OK too.

Comment: With `generate_vector_v()`, does it make a local `foo` and return its copy and then the local `foo` is erased? Or does it create a vector once and return itself without making any copy?

Comment: @Chang  It actually does neither, usually. You're putting the cart before the horse.  Just write good, readable, maintainable code first.

Comment: @Taekahn As my application is scientific computing, my learning objective for C++ is to learn how to write fast code.

Comment: @Chang If you want to write fast code, you should learn how to write good code first. Then once you've written good code, you can profile your application and find out where it needs to be fast. Trying to chase "what's the fastest way to do X in C++" is the worst possible way i can think of to try and learn it. Believe me, i've met people like that. Not only do they write crappy code, they write slow code. Their idea of how to write fast code is based on half truths, old/outdated information, etc. etc. A solid foundation in both C++ and in computer science is what should lead you.

Comment: @Chang `generate_vector_v()` is very fast. Most compilers will optimize the return so no copies are made. Worst case is the vector will be moved (very fast operation).

Comment: @Chang A nice thing about C++ is that even though you return a local object, the optimiser can - and in practice does - elide the object entirely. Even if it didn't, creation, move and destruction of the moved vector are all very fast operations.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it. I should've asked about it directly in this question.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to avail yourself of C++ feature like `new` and `delete` vs. `malloc` and `free`, but also of *more* modern C++ feature like `std::unique_ptr`.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using std::unique_ptr;
using std::make_unique;
using std::vector;

unique_ptr<vector<int>> generate_vector(vector<int>::size_type size) {
    return make_unique<vector<int>>(size);
}

int main() {
    const auto n = 10;

    auto ptr = generate_vector(n);

    for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        (*ptr)[i] = i;
    }

    for (const auto& i : *ptr) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But also why a `unique_ptr<vector<int>>` instead of just returning it by value?

Comment: Fair. This would scale better for large vectors. For trivial data, return by value is fine.

Comment: `vector` is at least one pointer to the data and typically two other book keeping variables for size and capacity (which also typically happen to be pointers). They move really cheaply and easily when they don't elide.

Comment: @Chris "This would scale better for large vectors. " barely if any due to move semantics

Comment: Also, offering an alternative to the raw pointer the OP demonstrated with `generate_vector_p`.